# Try to get weather data with swift - JSON OpenWeatherMap api

Tags: swift, macos, openweathermap

I have a problem with this code for macOS app..:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=\(city)&appid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")!) { data, response, error in
    if let error = error {
        print("Error:\n\(error)")
    } else {
        do {
            let weather = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: AnyObject]
            self.weatherLabel.stringValue = "Temperature \(weather["main"]!["temp"]!!)°C Humidity \(weather["main"]!["humidity"]!!)% Pressure \(weather["main"]!["pressure"]!!)hPa."
        } catch let jsonError as NSError {
            print("JSON error:\n\(jsonError.description)")
        }
    }
}.resume()
```

When try to get weather data there is error message:

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified
>   hostname could not be found."
>   UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x600000d076c0 {Error
>   Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1003 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-72000,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=10}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather.........

I try many different ways, but no success.. Is there anybody to know how to correct this function?

Comment: Drop the s, http://

Comment: Scheme and host are correct. Is `city` optional? And you will get another error (*`Any` has no subscript members*) in the line after the deserialization. Ans – as always – `mutableContainers` is pointless in Swift. Omit the `options` parameter.

Comment: You may need to update your code as vadian suggested, but before that, you need to check the Capabilities settings of your macOS app. When it is sandboxed, you need to set the Network settings properly, or else set App Sandbox to OFF.

Comment: Make sure to percent escape your `city` string before adding it to the url.

Comment: Thank you guys, the problem was about App Sandbox.. I set it to OFF and everything is ok now. Thanks, OOPer!

Comment: Rather than unsandboxing, you should just click on the “Outgoing Connections (Client)” capability for your target. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57527642/1271826